# Regex pattern construction dealing with recursion

Tags: php, regex

I'm not sure if recursion is the correct way to characterize what's occurring in this pattern, but unfortunately I'm too new with regex to build something that will conform to how this pattern can vary and avoid nested groups.

So the pattern is basically defined as:

```
@param {item} {label}:{text} {labeln}:{textn}
```

where `labeln` and `textn` is some N instance of the label:text group.

So an example would be

```
/**
 *
 * @param name1 test1:this is text for test1 test2:this is text for test2
 * @param name2 test3:this is text for test3 test4:this is text for test4 test5:this is text for test5
 *
 * /
```

Now ideally I'm trying to capture `name1`, `test1:this is text for test1`, and `test2:this is text for test2` as matching groups. Same goes for the `name2` line. Of course there can be many more examples of `name1` and the psuedo "named parameters" can be varied, from none to many. +Edit: Colons would not be permitted within the label text since they're reserved as delimiters. Label is strictly alphanumeric, label would probably be restricted to a-zA-Z0-9_,'"-

First question is... is this a recursion problem or did I mischaracterize this?

Second question is... is it possible and if so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have requirements on what can and can't be labels/texts?  It seems like labels would just be alphabetical characters followed by `:`, but then the text field seems a little difficult to grasp.  Is the first label's text `This is a variable: a`?  If so, how do we know that it isn't `This is a ` and the next label/text pair is `variable: a`?

Comment: Either way, its possible but it may be easiest to capture the param's name and label/texts group (in two groups) and then parse the label/texts group after-the-fact.

Comment: Indeed, I specifically made that label include a colon as I felt it would possibly break the pattern, however if it's not possible for such a pattern to work that could be a restricted character. Also, you're correct in stating a label would just be alphabetical, alphanumeric ideally.

Comment: Oh. I assumed you were using the ending `:` to signify "end of label description". Since this isn't the case, you'd need a way to differentiate between the start and end of the groups, otherwise your goal is impossible I'm afraid - no matter the tool you use. Perhaps something as simple as a capital letter or disallowing a literal `:` in the actual content.

Comment: @Sam Yes I think capturing the label:text as a group would be ideal as well.

Comment: @tenub Ah, no the colon is used to delimit the label and the label text. I threw that colon into the mix within the first label's text as a means to suggest that they would be permitted in the label text, but if that's not possible it could be restricted.

Comment: @CarlosRodrigues This is not recursion, recursion is needed when you have nested brackets for example and you want to match the right one `[test [nested] test2]`. Btw [*got* **regex**](http://regex101.com/r/nG8oE1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Preface:**

For the sake of explanation, I decided to clarify your "labels" by preceding them with a `%`.  This can be any reserved symbol or other pattern that helps clear up what is a label/text:

```
/**
 * @param variable_a %label:This is variable: a %required:true
 * @param variable_b %required:false %pattern:/[a-zA-Z:]/
 */
```

---

**Problem:**

The problem with capturing repetitive patterns in regular expressions is you can't have [an unknown amount of capture groups](http://regex101.com/r/oB7lV8) (i.e. you either need to match a global number of matches or capture a specific amount of groups in each match):

```
@param    (?# find a param)
\s*       (?# whitespace)
(\w+)     (?# capture the variable)
\s*       (?# whitespace)
(?:       (?# start non capturing group)
%(\w+):   (?# capture the label)
([^%\n]+) (?# capture the text)
)+        (?# repeat the non-capturing group)
```

In this example, I put the label/text capturing code in a non-capturing and repeated (1+ times) group.  This allows us to match the whole string, however only the last set of labels/texts are captured (since we only have 3 groups: variable, label, and text).

---

**Straightforward Solution:**

Instead of this, you can just [match the whole string](http://regex101.com/r/uM6qE3) and then [parse the label/text string](http://regex101.com/r/fE9rO7) after-the-fact:

```
(?# match the whole string)
@param    (?# find a param)
\s*       (?# whitespace)
(\w+)     (?# capture the variable)
\s*       (?# whitespace)
(.*)      (?# capture the labels/texts)

(?# parse the label/text string)
%         (?# the start of a label)
(\w+)     (?# capture label)
:         (?# end of label)
([^%]+)   (?# capture text)
```

---

**Awesome Solution:**

Finally, we can use some regular expression magic to do a global match of all label/text combinations.  This means we will have a defined set of 3 capture groups (variable, label, text) and we'll have a variable amount of matches.  I think this one is best to show and *then* explain, so here is the [crazy awesome regex magic](http://regex101.com/r/fC5xM4):

```
(?:       (?# start non-capturing group)
  @param  (?# find a param)
  \s*     (?# whitespace)
  (\w+)   (?# capture the variable)
  \s*     (?# whitespace)
 |        (?# OR)
  \G      (?# start back over from our last match)
)         (?# end non-capturing group)
%(\w+):   (?# capture the label)
([^%\n]+) (?# capture the text)
```

This one revolves around the PCRE magic of `\G`, which matches the end of the last match.  So we start a non-capturing group that will contain the "prefix" of a `@param` definition.  This will either match and capture the variable OR start over from the end of our last match.  Then we match/capture 1 label/text group.  Next time it is repeated, we will start where we left off, the ***variable capture group will be blank*** (since it doesn't exist that far into the string, you'll have to use logic to know which variable you are on), and capture another label/text group (until we hit a new line, since I said a text can't be `%` or `\n`).  Then the next match attempt will find a new variable defined by `@param`.  I think this will be your best option, it just takes some more logic on your end.

Comment: Well, that's just amazing. I'm blown away and this will more than suffice. It'll take me some time to digest all of the explanation, but I truly appreciate your time on this! Thank you!

Comment: Of course, hope it helps. You'll probably need to tweak the label/text logic to your needs, but this should be pretty for you to accomplish in [Regex101](http://regex101.com/).  Also, this currently requires at least one set of labels/texts..it shouldn't be too difficult to make it optional, though.

Comment: +1 for the \G ! I was trying with the recursion (?R) or (?0) as described here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html

Comment: @JorgeCampos, this example is best described as repetition (`[abc] [abc] [abc]`) rather than recursion (`[abc [abc] abc]`). I haven't played around with `(?R)` at all though, I'll have to check that documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you allow your *middle* label to contain a `:` but you don't allow it in your *end* label, I believe the below RegEx should work well enough:

```
@param\s+(.+?)\s+(.+:.+)\s+([^:]+:[^:]+)$
```

However, it won't work if your pattern spans multiple lines.

Also, if you're trying to *parse* PHPDoc or some variant thereof, you should write your own parser rather using RegEx.

Comment: Thanks for your time and insight! If I fail at having regex do some of the parsing legwork, I'll fall back to all programmatic logic. Thanks again.